# Memory error during dataframe creation in Python

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, dataset

Ehy guys

i had problem during the creation of my dataset with Python. 
I m doing this:

```
 userTab = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\anto-\\Desktop\\Ex. 
 Resource\\mapping_user_id.tsv',delimiter="\t",names = 
 ["User","Sequence"])

 wordTab = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\anto-\\Desktop\\Ex. 
 Resource\\mapping_word_id.tsv',delimiter="\t",names = 
 ["Word","Sequence"])



 df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index= userTab.User, columns=wordTab.Word)
```

I m trying to create a dataset from 2 elements, userTab.User are the row and wordTab.Word are the columns elements.
Maybe the shape is too big for compute in this way.
I print the shape of my element, because first all i think that i wrong the dimensions.

((603668,), (37419,), (603668, 37419))

after that i try to print the type, and my user and word are Seris element, and data is scipy.sparse.csc.csc_matrix

Maybe i need use chunk for this shape, but I seen the pandas.DataFrame reference and don't have an attribute.

I have a 8GB Ram on 64bit Python. The sparse matrix is in npz file (300mb about)

the error is general error:

```
   MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call 
   last)
   <ipython-input-26-ad363966ef6a> in <module>()
   10 type(sparse_matrix)
   11 
    ---> 12 df = pd.DataFrame(data=sparse_matrix, index= 
   np.array(userTab.User), columns= np.array(wordTab.Word))

   ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __init__(self, 
   data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
   416             if arr.ndim == 0 and index is not None and columns is not 
   None:
   417                 values = cast_scalar_to_array((len(index), 
   len(columns)),
   --> 418                                               data, dtype=dtype)
   419                 mgr = self._init_ndarray(values, index, columns,
   420                                          dtype=values.dtype, 
   copy=False)

   ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py in 
  cast_scalar_to_array(shape, value, dtype)
  1164         fill_value = value
 1165 
 -> 1166     values = np.empty(shape, dtype=dtype)
  1167     values.fill(fill_value)
  1168 

  MemoryError:
```

maybe the problem could be this, because i have a sort of ID that when i try to access at User column, id will be remain in userTab.User

[image]

Comment: How much memory is on your machine? What is throwing the actual memory error? How large is the CSV? These are all helpful pieces of info.

Comment: edit the question with this information

Comment: Awesome! This will help others give you a good answer.

Comment: That last shape has about 20 billion elements, which is rather more than you can store.

Comment: what is DATA in your code? from theshape, it looks like you are putting the whole dataset in EACH cell of the dataframe you are creating.

Comment: I can't do that, right? @DavisHerring

Comment: @MrE i wrote in my question, data is a scipy sparse matrix, with float elements... i just want put label on row and column of my matrix (so i try to cast in dataset)

Comment: @theantomc understood, but how comes it seems like your df ends up being of dimension 3, with the 3rd (i.e. each cell) being of the dimension of the full array? Somehow, you manage to map the whole array to each cell, which is why I wonder how you generated/loaded 'data', which is likely where you go wrong.

Comment: maybe i wrong with userTab and wordTab, because when i print i have 2 columns , one is id and other is my element...@MrE can be this?